# Disabling check statements in C++

Tags: c++

Say that my main code calls functions like `myarray(i)` where the length of `myarray` is `N`. During the development I would probably want to have a `CheckIndex` function inside the `()`overload. However, this turns out to waste computation time when the number of iterations is large. Another example would be to check if there is consistency in the dimensions of two matrices before adding them, or checking if the denominator in this expression `my_2D_array_instance/value` where `value` is a `double`, is not too small or zero.

My question is if there is a way to give the option to the user to tell the compiler "skip those checks" and if yes, how to do it?

Comment: Using preprocessor conditionals and macro definitions respectively (similar as with `DEBUG`) is one way.

Comment: Why are you managing arrays your own in c++? What's wrong with simply using [`std::array<T,Size>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Noteworthy that `std::array::at()` `std::vector::at()` already do bounds checking.

Comment: I should have written ```ScalarField(i,j)``` instead of ```myrray(i)```.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] as required here please. Without we can only speculate of what might be the best way for your (unknown) cases..

Comment: Use `assert` included in the `#include <cassert>`header..

Answer (score 1):

As πάντα ῥεῖ stated in the comment section you can use preprocessor conditionals to avoid compiling code you don't want to be part of the compilation, take the code:

```
    std::array<int, 5> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << a.at(5); //out of range
#endif

    std::cout << a.at(3);
```

With a *normal* compiler instruction the code inside `#ifdef` will not be compiled, but if you define `DEBUG` (you can name it whatever you want), when you compile it, ***i.e.***:

```
g++ main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -D DEBUG 
                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

All the code will be compiled.